# How to turn on STDOUT.sync in ruby from the command line

Tags: ruby, macos, io

I have objective-C code that calls ruby scripts and monitors STDOUT.  However, ruby does not seem to synchronise STDOUT by default, so I need to put `STDOUT.sync = true` at the beginning of the script to see output as it happens.

Can I do this as a command line option when calling a ruby script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a setup file to require before your script. Then call ruby with the `-r` flag:

```
ruby -r "$HOME/.rubyopts.rb" myscript.rb
```

You can also set the environment variable `RUBYOPT` to automatically include that file every time you run ruby:

```
export RUBYOPT="-r $HOME/.rubyopts.rb"
```