# Why does STDERR output from Ruby come before earlier STDOUT output when redirecting?

Tags: ruby, bash

In bash, this gives the output in the expected order:

```
ruby -e "puts 'one'; raise 'two'"
one
-e:1:in `<main>': two (RuntimeError)
```

But if I redirect STDERR to STDOUT, I get the error before the output, which I do not want:

```
ruby -e "puts 'one'; raise 'two'" 2>&1 | cat
-e:1:in `<main>': two (RuntimeError)
one
```

I want to redirect the output to a text file (it behaves the same way as `cat` above) and get both output and exceptions, but in the same order as when looking at the output in my terminal. Can this be achieved?

Comment: STDEER is always printed into the stream while STDOUT is usually buffered to be printed.

Answer (score 10):

This happens because of line-buffering vs block-buffering. You can control the type of buffering,  you can flush them at the point you want their output to be synced, or you can just wait until exit at which point everything gets flushed.  Unless you force it one way or the other, buffering depends on whether the output is a tty-type<sup>1</sup> file descriptor, so redirection into a pipe changes the mode.

Specifically:

```
                 true          false 
              ------------- --------------
$stdout.tty?  line-buffered block-buffered
$stderr.tty?  line-buffered line-buffered
```

You can configure them both the same way with:

```
$stdout.sync = $stderr.sync = true # or false, of course
```

My test case:

```
$stdout.sync = $stderr.sync = true
$stdout.puts 'stdout a'
sleep 2
$stdout.puts 'stdout b'
sleep 2
$stderr.puts 'stderr a'
sleep 2
$stderr.puts 'stderr b'
sleep 2
```

---

<sup>1. See ttyname(3).</sup>

Comment: Still helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because STDOUT doesn't always output right away, to force it to output you use `IO#flush`:

```
puts "one"
$>.flush
```

STDERR on the other hand always outputs immediately.

Comment: `IO#flush` is a better choice if there is a need for flushing the buffer more than once. `flush` is a single-flush, `sync` leaves the handle-down and you'll have to jiggle it to get it to stop running. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Maurício's and Gir Loves Tacos' answers, I came up with this (via [How to turn on STDOUT.sync in ruby from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537465/how-to-turn-on-stdout-sync-in-ruby-from-the-command-line)):

```
ruby -r "/tmp/sync.rb" -e "puts 'one'; raise 'two'" 2>&1 | cat
one
-e:1:in `<main>': two (RuntimeError)
```

where `/tmp/sync.rb` contains

```
STDOUT.sync=true
```

Or if you can modify the script itself, add that line to the beginning.

Thank you!

Comment: This is what I ended up using it for: https://github.com/henrik/vim-ruby-runner/commit/d4b8cee927a265bbd016a42cf98f570eb33512ad

Answer (score 0):

`ruby -e STDOUT.sync=true -e "puts 'one'; raise 'two'" 2>&1 | cat`

should do it