# Unexpected errors output order

Tags: ruby

Having this code:

```
# $stderr.sync = false
warn 'warn'
$stderr.puts 'err'
fail
```

When I run it like this `ruby test.rb 2>err.log`, output is ok:

```
warn
err
test.rb:3:in `<main>': unhandled exception
```

But when I uncomment the first line — the output is different:

```
warn
test.rb:3:in `<main>': unhandled exception
err
```

Why buffered output to the `$stderr` redirected to file has the **wrong order**?
If we do not redirect to the file — the order is ok (exception is the last line of the output).
`warn` was added thanks to the comment below.

This is not the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901524/why-does-stderr-output-from-ruby-come-before-earlier-stdout-output-when-redirect), here I do not mix stdout and stderr.

Checked platforms:
`Windows10: Ruby v3.0.2.107 (2021-07-07) [x64-mingw32]`
`Linux: Ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Looks like a ruby bug to me

Comment: I can't reproduce this (MRI Ruby 2.6.4 and jruby 1.7.27). What happens if you add a few more `puts` before the `fail`? What happens if you do **not** redirect the error output to a file? I can't even imagine a Ruby bug which would show up in **this** way.

Comment: It may be platform dependant (today reproduced also on Linux with Ruby 3). More puts appear after the exception. If we do not redirect to the file — the order is ok (exception is the last line of the output)

Comment: Using `warn` instead of `$stderr.puts` results in the correct order regardless of the sync state. Maybe the internal error handling bypasses the buffer and writes directly to stderr.

Comment: @Stefan, thank you — added `warn` to the post.

Comment: Reported an issue — https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18244